# RESTful and Resource Controllers in Laravel 4 and 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

RESTful and Resource controllers in Laravel 4 are limited that is RESTful method names has to end with get,put,post,patch,delete and Resource controllers has to end with index, create, store,show edit,update,destroy. My question is does Laravel 5 impose the same restrictions?

Comment: there is no restrictions even at laravel 4. You can add route as many as you want based on what you need. Laravel `route::resource` only to help you make a cleaner code rather than you need to type each of them and it generate based on general API need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Preface

Natively, **Yes, it does**. Read [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#restful-resource-controllers). But if you want something different, I give you a trick to do this. First, you may create your own `ResourceRegistrar`. Mine is [located in `app/Routing/ResourceRegistrar.php`]:

```
namespace App\Routing;

use Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar as BaseRegistrar;

class ResourceRegistrar extends BaseRegistrar
{
}
```

Then register your own `RouteRegistrar` in your service provider:

```
$this->app->bind('Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar', 'App\Routing\ResourceRegistrar');
```

> Notes: I register my own `RouteRegistrar` in `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` via `register` method.

### Example

I add my own resource controller in `routes.php` something like this:

```
Route::resource('photo', 'PhotoController');
```

So, I should have a `PhotoController` to handle this request.

### Implementation

We know, that a `GET` request to '/photo' will be handled by `PhotoController@index` method, to modify your `photo:index` action to `photo:root` action, modify your `ResourceRegistrar` to something like this:

```
namespace App\Routing;

use Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar as BaseRegistrar;

class ResourceRegistrar extends BaseRegistrar
{
    protected function addResourceIndex($name, $base, $controller, $options)
    {
        $uri = $this->getResourceUri($name);

        $action = $this->getResourceAction($name, $controller, 'root', $options);

        return $this->router->get($uri, $action);
    }
}
```

So now `GET` request to '/photo' will be handled by `PhotoController@root` method.

### Cheat Sheet

```
Verb      | Path                  | Method to modify  |
----------|-----------------------|-----------------  |
GET       | `/photo`              | addResourceIndex  |
GET       | `/photo/create`       | addResourceCreate |
POST      | `/photo`              | addResourceStore  |
GET       | `/photo/{photo}`      | addResourceShow   |
GET       | `/photo/{photo}/edit` | addResourceEdit   |
PUT/PATCH | `/photo/{photo}`      | addResourceUpdate |
DELETE    | `/photo/{photo}`      | addResourceDestroy|
```

See the base code of `ResourceRegistrar` [here](https://github.com/illuminate/routing/blob/master/ResourceRegistrar.php).